# Register Multiple Components for Single Interface Using Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, nhibernate, castle-windsor

I am trying to register multiple NHibernate ISessions (multiple databases) by using the code below. I am getting "There is a component already registered for the given key Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.GenericFactory`1[[NHibernate.ISession, NHibernate, Version=2.1.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4]]" as the error message when the container is trying to be built.

```
container.Kernel.Register(
    Component.For<ISession>().LifeStyle.Transient
        .UsingFactoryMethod(() => sessionFactoryOne.OpenSession()
        ).Named("ISession+sessionOne"));

container.Kernel.Register(
    Component.For<ISession>().LifeStyle.Transient
        .UsingFactoryMethod(() => sessionFactoryTwo.OpenSession())
         .Named("ISession+sessionTwo"));
```

Comment: That's bizzare. Which version are you using? What happens if you move .Named() before .UsingFactoryMethod() ?

Comment: I'm using version 2.0.0.5642  When I moved .Named() before the factory method I get the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [fixed a couple of months ago](http://fisheye2.atlassian.com/changelog/castleproject/?cs=5927). Please get a recent build from the [buildserver](http://www.castleproject.org:8090/viewType.html?buildTypeId=bt2&page=3&tab=buildTypeHistoryList&guest=1).